# Getting java.io.IOException: Canceled when I navigate from a fragment to another

Tags: android, android-fragments, okhttp, interceptor

In my Android app, I have a `BottomNavigationView` with **4 items**.

I am able to reproduce an issue that produces the following stack trace when I navigate to fragment 1.

What is strange is the issue occurred only **when a navigate from fragment 2 to fragment 1**. (The issue doesn't appear when I navigate from fragment 3 to fragment 1 for example)

Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.io.IOException: Canceled
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:65)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
        at com.ale.omniaccessassettracking.interceptor.ServiceInterceptor.intercept(ServiceInterceptor.kt:35)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
        at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.kt:150)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.kt:184)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:136)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Comment: Are you making a network call in your fragment 2, that gets interrupted before it ends when you navigate away?

Comment: Hi @MarioHuizinga Yes, I have a network call in both fragment, but I'm well waiting the end of those before navigating.

Comment: Maybe your fragment 3 is already created when fragment 2 is visible. And fragment 3 gets destroyed when you navigate from 2 to 1. Maybe include some log statements to see what is happening.